# DrawRectangleBrick() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to create a brick wall using turtle for my python coding class and I cannot figure out why I am receiving the error
"DrawRectangleBrick() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'"
here is where the issue is:

```
def DrawRectangleBrick(x,y):
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    for i in range(4):
        if i% 2 == 0:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE * 2)
            tr.left(90)
        else:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
            tr.left(90)
```

here is the beginning of my code:

```
import turtle

SQUARE_SIZE = 40
tr = turtle.Turtle()


def InitTurtle():
    scr = turtle.Screen()
    tr.color("black")
    tr.width("1")
    tr.speed(20)
    tr.penup()
    tr.goto(-300,-300)
    tr.pendown()

def DrawSquareBrick(x,y):
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    for i in range(4):
        tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
        tr.left(90)

def DrawRectangleBrick(x,y):
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    for i in range(4):
        if i% 2 == 0:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE * 2)
            tr.left(90)
        else:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
            tr.left(90)
```

Edit:

here is the full code:

```
import turtle

SQUARE_SIZE = 40
tr = turtle.Turtle()


def InitTurtle():
    scr = turtle.Screen()
    tr.color("black")
    tr.width("1")
    tr.speed(20)
    tr.penup()
    tr.goto(-300,-300)
    tr.pendown()

def DrawSquareBrick(x,y):
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    for i in range(4):
        tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
        tr.left(90)

def DrawRectangleBrick(x,y):
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    for i in range(4):
        if i% 2 == 0:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE * 2)
            tr.left(90)
        else:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
            tr.left(90)

def DrawRowOfRectangleBricks(yPos):
   global SQUARE_SIZE
   xPos = -300
   tr.pendown()
   for i in range(8):
       DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
       xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
   tr.penup()

def DrawRowOfBricksStartingWithSquare(yPos):
    global SQUARE_SIZE
    xPos = -300
    tr.pendown()
    for i in range:
        DrawSquareBrick(xPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
        XPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
        XPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
        XPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
        XPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
        XPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
        XPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
        XPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawSquareBrick(xPos)
    tr.penup()

def main():
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    InitTurtle()
    yPos = -300

    for i in range(8):
        DrawRowOfRectangleBricks(yPos)
        yPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRowOfBricksStartingWithSquare(yPos)
        yPos += SQUARE_SIZE

main()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Where is the code which calls the `DrawRectangleBrick` function?

Comment: you need to post the Turtle class, so we can reproduce and give you a solution.

Comment: I think you need to change `DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)` to `DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)`

Comment: You defined `DrawSquareBrick()` and `DrawRectangleBrick()` to take two parameters (`x` and `y`).  But in every place where you call one of these functions, you only supply one parameter.  Where are you expecting the other parameter's value to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `DrawRectangleBrick` takes to parameters `x` and `y`. You need to call the function with 2 parameters as well.

So, change all your

```
DrawRectangleBrick(xPos)
```

to

```
DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
```