# Python turtle drawing a brick wall

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, python-turtle

I am attempting to create a brick wall in my python class and we have to use a certain template which I have followed except there is one issue. When I run the code, rather than the bricks being drawn in different places, they are all drawn in the exact same place. I am new to python so forgive me if this is obvious.

I am trying to use a global and adding on to the global to place the bricks in different places but I cannot get it to work. Here is my code:

```
import turtle

SQUARE_SIZE = 40
tr = turtle.Turtle()


def InitTurtle():
    scr = turtle.Screen()
    tr.color("black")
    tr.width("1")
    tr.speed(2)
    tr.penup()
    tr.goto(-300,-300)
    tr.pendown()

def DrawSquareBrick(xPos, yPos):
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    for i in range(4):
        tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
        tr.left(90)

def DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos):
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    for i in range(4):
        if i% 2 == 0:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE * 2)
            tr.left(90)
        else:
            tr.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
            tr.left(90)
            
def DrawRowOfBricksStartingWithSquare(yPos):
    global SQUARE_SIZE
    xPos = -300
    tr.pendown()
    for i in range:
        DrawSquareBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
        xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawSquareBrick(xPos, yPos)
    tr.penup()
    
def DrawRowOfRectangleBricks(yPos):
   global SQUARE_SIZE
   xPos = -300
   tr.pendown()
   for i in range(8):
       DrawRectangleBrick(xPos, yPos)
       xPos += SQUARE_SIZE
   tr.penup()

def main():
    global SQUARE_SIZE

    InitTurtle()
    yPos = -300

    for i in range(8):
        DrawRowOfBricksStartingWithSquare(yPos)
        yPos += SQUARE_SIZE
        DrawRowOfRectangleBricks(yPos)
        yPos += SQUARE_SIZE

main()
turtle.done()
```

Edit: my professor is requiring that we use globals for this assignment

Comment: Did you notice that your `DrawSquareBrick` and `DrawRectangleBrick` functions accept two parameters, and then does not use either of them?

Comment: And you do not need a `global` statement unless you are changing the value.  None of yours are needed.  You are USING globals, but you don't need the `global` statement.  This is not what it used for.

Comment: Remember that the turtle tracks its own position.  Instead of `xPos += SQUARE_SIZE`, you need something like `penup` and `forward(SQUARE_SIZE)`.

Comment: Related: [DrawRectangleBrick() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323996/drawrectanglebrick-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y)

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable` when I run this code, different than what's being asked about.